# Scroll not working in update panel having more than one div sections

Tags: asp.net

I have an update panel. Top section of the update panel should be freeze and bottom section should be scrollable. So I have divided the update panel into two ; one having fixed width and with no scroll and the other having scroll.  See code below:

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <asp:Panel ID="ControlBar" runat="server" CssClass="Toolbar">
                    <%--Some popup buttons are here -->
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>

            <div id="scrollableSectionDiv" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 88%; overflow: auto;">
  <%--Some fields are here -->
</div>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have a drop down in the second  which fills another drop down based on the value which refreshes the UpdatePanel. Problem is after reloading of UpdatePanel scroll is not accurate and it is not showing all the controls below i.e. scroll is not complete. But if I re-size the browser or simply refresh the browser, scroll starts working. Please provide some solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the Panel control instead of the second div?

```
<style type="text/css">
.scrollingControlContainer
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 490px;
}

.scrollingList
{
    border: 1px Black solid;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 500px;
}
</style>

<asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" 
       ScrollBars="Auto"  
       CssClass="scrollingControlContainer scrollingList"> 
        <div style="height:88%">
           <%--Some fields are here --%>
        </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Please note that you shoudn't set Panel width and height in percentage.

Comment: Yes I have tried this as well. With fixed dimensions this solution is working but I can not hard code the values. So I have even tried using CssClass with min-width and min-height. But that is also not working. One more weird issue is, if I specify the height only things are working except the horizontal scroll bar. But if I specify both height and width then I am facing the same problem.

Comment: I don't know why you need to set panel height as percentage, if you do like that the panel or div will expand following the content's height, then it doesn't matter to have scroll bar.

Comment: Because, lets say I specify height as 500px. This will add scroll for the control outside this range and it will set the height of the scroll as 500. Now suppose user change the resolution to a higher one, the space on the web page will be more but still there will be a scroll on that section in spite of free space. Don't you thing this will look ugly?

Comment: I've edited my answer, not sure if it will work. If not, I think you may try Javascript instead.

Comment: I got the resolution, anyways thanks a lot for your help. I have taken a table and put this panel inside that table with position of panel as absolute in table. Now I can give size in percentage as well. There was a minor issue of maintaining scroll bar position after post back with this change which I got resolved using javascript.

Comment: Great! Finally you got a solution ^^

Comment: not great: didn't post solution / said javascript... it's the whole purpose of this site! @user2990950 looks like you might be inactive, if not could you share your solution as an answer?